# Pyspark dataframe write and read changes schema

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe which contains both string and int columns.

But when I write the dataframe to a csv file and then load it later, the all the columns are loaded as string.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alberto", 2), ("Dakota", 2)], 
                              ["Name", "count"])
```

Before:

```
df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
  |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
  |-- count: long (nullable = true)


df.write.mode('overwrite').option('header', True).csv(filepath)

new_df = spark.read.option('header', True).csv(filepath)
```

After:

```
new_df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
  |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
  |-- count: string (nullable = true)
```

How do I specify to store the schema as well while writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `don't have to specify schema` while writing but we can specify the **`schema`** while reading.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
schema = StructType(
   [
     StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('count', LongType(), True)
   ]
 )

#specify schema while reading
new_df = spark.read.schema(schema).option('header', True).csv(filepath)
new_df.printSchema()

#or else use inferschema option as true but specifying schema will be more robust
new_df = spark.read.option('header', True).option("inferSchema",True).csv(filepath)
```

Comment: I do not know all the column names in advance when I'm loading the file. Can I specify one column as string and then default all other columns to long?

Comment: @ThirupathiThangavel, Then it's better to use `inferSchema` option we don't need to know all column names before in this case (or) else you need to **construct schema dynamically** then pass the schema while reading csv file using `.schema` option.